# How to get next weekday number

Tags: linux, date, sh

In Debian 6 Linux  shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
backupday=$(date +%u)
```

assings weekday number to backupday variable.
In my Linux

```
Monday returns 1
Thuesday returns 2
...
Saturady returns 6
Sunday returns 7
```

How to get next day weekday number:

```
Monday should return 2
Thuesday should return 3
...
Saturady should return 7
Sunday should return 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the `FORMAT` Interpreted sequences `%w` instead of `%u`.

It start with Saturday (`%w day of week (0..6); 0 is Sunday`). 
And it's easy to plus 1 to get what your want.

```sh
$ echo $(($(date +%w --date=Saturday) + 1))
7
$ echo $(($(date +%w --date=Sunday) + 1))
1
$ echo $(($(date +%w --date=Monday) + 1))
2
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
$ echo $(( $(date +%u --date=Saturday) % 7 + 1 ))
7
$ echo $(( $(date +%u --date=Sunday) % 7 + 1 ))
1
$ echo $(( $(date +%u --date=Monday) % 7 + 1 ))
2
```